# Excel udf: sum from numbers in mixed text cells from corresponding duplicates in list

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

I have a list similar to this:

```
G:1 Diagonal Lattice - 5/16" Lath (1x2 Framed) S.S (PW)          O:1 4 p
G:2 DLT (Diagonal Lattice Top) 2x4 Fr 1x6 T&G Y-Brds             O:2 12PCS
G:3 Diagonal Lattice - 5/16" Lath (1x2 Framed) S.S (PW)          O:3 3pc
G:4 Diagonal Lattice - 5/16" Lath (1x2 Framed) S.S (PW)          O:4 6 pc
G:5 DLT (Diagonal Lattice Top) 2x4 Fr 1x6 T&G Y-Brds             O:5 4 PC
G:6 SLT (Square Lattice Top) 2x3 OT3 Fr 1x4 T&G                  O:6 2pcs
```

I don't want to adjust the list, I merely need to sum the values.

The desired Result is this:

```
T:1 Diagonal Lattice - 5/16" Lath (1x2 Framed) S.S (PW)           U:1 16
T:2 DLT (Diagonal Lattice Top) 2x4 Fr 1x6 T&G Y-Brds              U:2 13
T:3 SLT (Square Lattice Top) 2x3 OT3 Fr 1x4 T&G                   U:3 2
```

Because of the mixed text, I am unable to use sumif without errors, at least so far.

Labels - Item = G1:G3701
         Qty = O1:O3701

```
={sumif(Item, T1, Qty)}
={sumif(Item, T1, value(left(Qty, find("p",Qty)-1)))}
```

Neither of these work.
I've tried to add a function to take the numbers out.

```
={sumif(Item, T1, getNumeric(Qty))}
```

But, I believe it fails for the same reason.

I've tested the getNumeric function and it works outside of sumif
I made a pivot table to pull the distinct values and put in order, that part is easy. But I can't add up the Tally values, or don't know how.

Is there a udf that will work?

edit:fixed to give clearer desired result, sry.

Comment: Excel works best with properly structured data. Can you filter the data to just remove the strings and leave only the numbers? A tool like [ASAP Utilities](https://www.asap-utilities.com/) might help.

Comment: I have a few thousand rows to filter through. I'm trying to avoid changing the original sheet. Are you suggesting copying all items to another sheet and then calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the pieces abbreviation is always there AND it always starts with P AND the number is always to the left of it on its own you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=C1)*LEFT($B$1:$B$6,SEARCH("p",$B$1:$B$6)-1))
```

[image: POC]

To deal with the case where you have a number with no "pcs" type text after it.  in other words its actually a number.  I would employ a helper column for strip out the number, then perform a sumif or sumifs type function using the helper column for the sum.

### UPDATE

Same formula works with the new example data and adjusted for new columns:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($G$1:$G$6=T1)*LEFT($O$1:$O$6,SEARCH("p",$O$1:$O$6)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does work in this example. I should have put in some actual data, so I apologize. I thought the data should work the same. Column B would be the same data. However, the row data is something like : 2x3 Frame Solid (1x4 T&G)    
2x3 Frame Solid (1x4 T&G) GRN 6'x8'
2x3 Frame Solid (1x6 T&G) GRN 6'x8'

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(($G$1:$G$3701=G33)*LEFT($O$1:$O$3701,SEARCH("p",$O$1:$O$3701)-1)) - this gives me a #VALUE error - items are in column g, quantities in o, g33 being an example of one duplicate to find

Comment: You need a list of items you want to sum for like you do in column C in your original example.  reference your G33 to this column.   Not sure, but a blank as well as an actual number in column 0 may cause things to blow up.

Comment: the problem you may be having is that you have an actual number in your list.  when I changes your sample data from `6 pc` to `6`, it gave me the same error #value.  To get around that you can try the following formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(($G$1:$G$6=T2)*IFERROR(LEFT($O$1:$O$6,SEARCH("p",$O$1:$O$6)-1),$O$1:$O$6))`

Comment: Thank you @ForwardEd. I believe I will have to separate the data to make it work.  I would prefer a udf to go through and step by step calculate the translated data, but you have been helpful.